# Applying CSS rules on repeating divs in IE8

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page where I have divs with fieldsets comprising of labels and input elements (for the most part).    I identify the divs by id and apply the styling using CSS rules and it works great.   However, i have a div in the page that could appear one or more times.   I try to identify the repeating divs by class name and I'm not sure how I can apply the the styling rules on the labels within these repeating divs.

When the div is identified by the id, i do something like:

```
#employeeDiv fieldset label{
//style element here
}
```

however, if i have a div identified by classname, how do i accomplish the same behavior as above without adding style info to the individual labels?    Browser is IE8.   I'm able to use jquery or CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.divClass fieldset label{
   //style element here
}
```